# Error uploading Dicom files using Clear Canvas library

Tags: .net, dicom, clearcanvas

i am attempting to publish Dicom file to a remote PACS using the ClearCanvas dlls.  I can use the ClearCanvas libraries to open the DICOM files, update tags in the file and save the file.  When I try and publish the files (ClearCanvas.ImageViewer.Services.DicomFilePublisher.PublishRemote) to the remote PACS I get the following error:

I've  replaced the IP with xx. and the AE information with AE_Name

```
2012-02-02 18:11:38,141 [Send to xx.xx.xx.xxx/AE_NAME:7400] INFO  - Preparing to connect to AE AE_NAME on host xx.xx.xx.xxx on port 7400 and sending 105 images.
2012-02-02 18:11:42,344 [11] INFO  - Large object collection summary: freed 0 MB in 0 seconds and 0 iterations, Total Containers: 0, Total Large Objects: 0
2012-02-02 18:11:48,141 [Send to xx.xx.xx.xxx/AE_NAME:7400] ERROR - Exception thrown

Exception attempting connection to RemoteHost AE_NAME (xx.xx.xx.xxx:7400)
ClearCanvas.Dicom.Network.DicomNetworkException: Timeout while attempting to connect to remote server xx.xx.xx.xxx:7400
at ClearCanvas.Dicom.Network.DicomClient.Connect(IPEndPoint ep)
at ClearCanvas.Dicom.Network.DicomClient.Connect()
at ClearCanvas.Dicom.Network.Scu.ScuBase.Connect()
2012-02-02 18:11:48,141 [Send to xx.xx.xx.x/AE_Name:7400] ERROR - Error encountered while sending file C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\ClearCanvas\Publishing\AE_Name.longfilename.dcm (AE_Name: The association was aborted.).
```

I have the ClearCanvas workstation installed on the computer and I can upload and download files from within the workstation application.  Is there anyway to determine if this a timeout issue, or another more specific connection issue?  If it is a timeout, is there a way to increase the timeout setting?

Thanks for help/suggestions.  If anything isn't clear please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a suspicion that this is a false error, and the reason it is failing is that the user account under which the Workstation service is running doesn't have access to the temp folder the files are being written to. Try giving full access on that folder to "Everyone" and see if the problem goes away.

Another way to test it independently of your own code is:

1. In the Workstation, define the server as a "default" server (Tools/Options/Default Servers)
2. Open a local study from "My Studies"
3. Create a key image
4. Close the study

Do you get the same message in the logs? When you create a key image, the DicomFilePublisher is used to send the newly created key images to other servers.

Also, I doubt it will provide much insight, but you can enable debug logging in the logging.config file by changing "INFO" to "DEBUG". You'll get more info in the logs related to the DICOM communication.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I am now able to publish the files to a remote server!!  Thanks!